# How to otimize select from several tables with millions of rows

Tags: oracle, optimization, tree, indexing

Have the following tables (Oracle 10g):

```
catalog (
  id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR2(255),
  owner NUMBER,
  root NUMBER REFERENCES catalog(id)
  ...
)
university (
  id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
)
securitygroup (
  id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
  ...
)
catalog_securitygroup (
  catalog REFERENCES catalog(id),
  securitygroup REFERENCES securitygroup(id)
)
catalog_university (
  catalog REFERENCES catalog(id),
  university REFERENCES university(id)
)
```

Catalog: 500 000 rows, catalog_university: 500 000, catalog_securitygroup: 1 500 000.

I need to select any 50 rows from catalog with specified root ordered by name for current university and current securitygroup. There is a query:

```
SELECT ccc.* FROM (
  SELECT cc.*, ROWNUM AS n FROM (
      SELECT c.id, c.name, c.owner
        FROM catalog c, catalog_securitygroup cs, catalog_university cu
        WHERE c.root = 100
          AND cs.catalog = c.id
          AND cs.securitygroup = 200
          AND cu.catalog = c.id
          AND cu.university = 300
        ORDER BY name
    ) cc 
) ccc WHERE ccc.n > 0 AND ccc.n <= 50;
```

Where 100 - some catalog, 200 - some securitygroup, 300 - some university. This query return 50 rows from ~ 170 000 in 3 minutes.

But next query return this rows in 2 sec:

```
SELECT ccc.* FROM (
  SELECT cc.*, ROWNUM AS n FROM (
      SELECT c.id, c.name, c.owner
        FROM catalog c
        WHERE c.root = 100
        ORDER BY name
    ) cc 
) ccc WHERE ccc.n > 0 AND ccc.n <= 50;
```

I build next indexes: (catalog.id, catalog.name, catalog.owner), (catalog_securitygroup.catalog, catalog_securitygroup.index), (catalog_university.catalog, catalog_university.university).

Plan for first query (using PLSQL Developer):

http://habreffect.ru/66c/f25faa5f8/plan2.jpg

Plan for second query:

http://habreffect.ru/f91/86e780cc7/plan1.jpg

What are the ways to optimize the query I have?

Comment: +1 for completness, can you add EXPLAIN PLANS for the both queries?

Comment: As i wrote above, I need to select 50 (0-50 or 50-100 or 100-150 etc.) rows from catalog with specified root ordered by name for current university and current securitygroup. Each catalog can be accessible to certain universities and security group. And each catalog shows 50 results per page.

Comment: LMFAO, @Anton, is that last comment supposed to be an EXPLAIN PLAN? I think so... it's not an explanation of a plan, it's the optimizers "road map" for how to execute the query. What tool are you using and we can tell you how to get the plan.

Comment: added, if picture is too small, i will reupload

Comment: not too small, but you could have expanded the columns for cost, cardinality and bytes.

Comment: btw, with proper indexes your query will run under 1s

Comment: Nice @unreason... you built a sample to test. Excellent!

Comment: @Anton, do read my answer - I believe it is mistake for you to denormalize at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I assume that your University and SecurityGroup tables are rather small. You posted the size of the large tables but it's really the other sizes that are part of the problem

Your problem is from the fact that you can't join the smallest tables first. Your join order should be from small to large. But because your mapping tables don't include a securitygroup-to-university table, you can't join the smallest ones first. So you wind up starting with one or the other, to a big table, to another big table and then with that large intermediate result you have to go to a small table.

If you always have current_univ and current_secgrp and root as inputs you want to use them to filter as soon as possible. The only way to do that is to change your schema some. In fact, you can leave the existing tables in place if you have to but you'll be adding to the space with this suggestion.

You've normalized the data very well. That's great for speed of update... not so great for querying. We denormalize to speed querying (that's the whole reason for datawarehouses (ok that and history)). Build a single mapping table with the following columns.

Univ_id, SecGrp_ID, Root, catalog_id. Make it an index organized table of the first 3 columns as pk.

Now when you query that index with all three PK values, you'll finish that index scan with a complete list of allowable catalog Id, now it's just a single join to the cat table to get the cat item details and you're off an running.

Comment: It helped !) Now query runs in ~3.5 seconds. I'll do a couple of tests

Comment: But i also add catalog_id in PK.

Comment: @Stephanie, not really correct to say from smallest table to largest table; better is to say from highest selectivity conditions towards lowest. And that's what the planer will do, analyze the cost of possible paths.

Comment: Absolutely. When you're done with the big mapping table, you'll be doing a lookup into the catalog table by PK value so an index will help. BTW if you build an index on Catalog.id, catalog.name, catalog.owner and then build the PK constraint with the "USING INDEX" clause.. You will avoid doing any table reads at all since the select columns are completely contained in the index.

Comment: @Stephanie Page, your analysis is ok, but.. I don't agree that this should be tried first. I believe that in the last update of my answer I offer better approach and explanation - would be interested to hear if I made any mistakes...

Comment: @Stephanie, I'll let Anton be the judge of that (I would argue that my solution is significantly better because it provides better explanation what is happening and does not promote unnecessary denormalization, but I am, off course biased :) )

Comment: You're right about the bias but it's not what I think you're saying - because the answer is yours, right? The bias is that the more normalized a database is, the better it is period. I see normalization as a tool. I use it when it makes things better, not because it's my goal to use it. My mantra is, Normalize to speed maintenance, denormalize to speed query. Which is exactly the dichotomy between OLTP and OLAP systems.

Comment: Or I'm completely wrong. Either way, both answer work. The real question for Anton to decide is do they continue to work with everything else he needs to build. One solution to one problem isn't where the story ends. Often that solution spawns far worse problems or has no impact requiring fix after fix after fix for successive issues.

Comment: @Stephanie, well my mantra is very similar to yours: *'denormalize when necessary to increase query speed (at the expense of maintenance and/or update performance)'*. here it is not necessary. that's all there is to it. and that's the only reason, i hope, that i prefer my answer. (note: my mantra for indexes is very simliar - *'add indexes when necessary to increase query speed (at the expense of update performance)'*. In this sense, conceptually, indexes are transparent denormalization natively supported and maintained by RDBMS.

Answer (score 3):

The indexes that can be useful and should be considered deal with

```
WHERE c.root = 100
      AND cs.catalog = c.id
      AND cs.securitygroup = 200
      AND cu.catalog = c.id
      AND cu.university = 300
```

So the following fields can be interesting for indexes

```
c: id, root   
cs: catalog, securitygroup   
cu: catalog, university
```

So, try creating

```
(catalog_securitygroup.catalog, catalog_securitygroup.securitygroup)
```

and

```
(catalog_university.catalog, catalog_university.university)
```

**EDIT:**
I missed the ORDER BY - these fields should also be considered, so

```
(catalog.name, catalog.id)
```

might be beneficial (or some other composite index that could be used for sorting *and* the conditions - possibly (catalog.root, catalog.name, catalog.id))

**EDIT2**
Although another question is accepted I'll provide some more food for thought.
I have created some test data and run some benchmarks.

The test cases are minimal in terms of record width (in catalog_securitygroup and catalog_university the primary keys are (catalog, securitygroup) and (catalog, university)). Here is the number of records per table:

```
test=# SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM catalog), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM catalog_securitygroup), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM catalog_university);
 ?column? | ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------+----------
   500000 |  1497501 |   500000
(1 row)
```

Database is postgres 8.4, default ubuntu install, hardware i5, 4GRAM

First I rewrote the query to

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.owner
FROM catalog c, catalog_securitygroup cs, catalog_university cu
WHERE c.root < 50 
  AND cs.catalog = c.id 
  AND cu.catalog = c.id
  AND cs.securitygroup < 200
  AND cu.university < 200
ORDER BY c.name
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 100
```

note: the conditions are turned into less then to maintain comparable number of intermediate rows (the above query would return 198,801 rows without the LIMIT clause)

If run as above, without any extra indexes (save for PKs and foreign keys) it runs in **556 ms** on a cold database (this is actually indication that I oversimplified the sample data somehow - I would be happier if I had 2-4s here without resorting to less then operators)

This bring me to my point - any straight query that only joins and filters (certain number of tables) and returns only a certain number of the records should run under 1s on any decent database without need to use cursors or to denormalize data (one of these days I'll have to write a post on that).

Furthermore, if a query is returning only 50 rows and does simple equality joins and restrictive equality conditions it should run even much faster.

Now let's see if I add some indexes, the biggest potential in queries like this is usually the sort order, so let me try that:

```
CREATE INDEX test1 ON catalog (name, id);
```

This makes execution time on the query - **22ms** on a cold database.

And **that's** the point - if you are trying to get only a page of data, you should only get a page of data and execution times of queries such as this on **normalized** data with proper **indexes** should take less then 100ms on decent hardware.

I hope I didn't oversimplify the case to the point of no comparison (as I stated before some simplification is present as I don't know the cardinality of relationships between catalog and the many-to-many tables).

So, the conclusion is

- if I were you I would not stop tweaking indexes (and the SQL) until I get the performance of the query to go below 200ms as rule of the thumb.
- only if I would find an objective explanation why it can't go below such value I would resort to denormalisation and/or cursors, etc...

Comment: The database with which I work very big: 585 tables. I have a catalog which has 180 000 childs. The following tables I used for test: catalog with pk (id) build using index (id, name, owner) - 500 000 rows, catalog_university with pk(catalog, university) - 500 000 rows (for each catalog - 1 university), catalog_securitygroup with pk(catalog, securitygroup) - 1 500 000 rows (for each catalog - 3 security groups). First query (for selecting 180 000 childs) from my question run in 3.6 sec with this setup. With denormalization it runs in 1.3 sec.

Comment: I want to say, that the problem now in sorting 180 000 rows by name. Wihout sorting query runs in 62 ms

Comment: @Anton, number of tables does not matter and I created the same number of rows as you have (though you might have many more columns, which would slow down execution time by some factor if not all columns covered by indexes, also the cardinality of relationships might be different in my sample, but I tried to compensate for that, see the answer - but i repeat myself, see answer again; bottom line is that you should be able to go below 1s without denormalization; your figure of 62 ms is the kind of performance you should expect provided planer will use index for sorting...

Comment: ..all of which reinforce my argument that you should *optimize your indexes first*, and only after that try other solutions. for example index (id, name, owner) is useless for sorting by name (since it is in order of id, and out of order on name). try creating index just on name, or (name, id) - that is what did the trick for me (drop from 556ms to 22ms).

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle cost-based optimizer makes use of all the information that it has to decide what the best access paths are for the data and what the least costly methods are for getting that data. So below are some random points related to your question.

The first three tables that you've listed all have primary keys. Do the other tables (catalog_university and catalog_securitygroup) also have primary keys on them?? A primary key defines a column or set of columns that are non-null and unique and are very important in a relational database.

Oracle generally enforces a primary key by generating a unique index on the given columns. The Oracle optimizer is more likely to make use of a unique index if it available as it is more likely to be more selective.

If possible an index that contains unique values should be defined as unique (`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX...`) and this will provide the optimizer with more information.

The additional indexes that you have provided are no more selective than the existing indexes. For example, the index on (catalog.id, catalog.name, catalog.owner) is unique but is less useful than the existing primary key index on (catalog.id). If a query is written to select on the catalog.name column, it is possible to do and index skip scan but this starts being costly (and most not even be possible in this case).

Since you are trying to select based in the catalog.root column, it might be worth adding an index on that column. This would mean that it could quickly find the relevant rows from the catalog table. The timing for the second query could be a bit misleading. It might be taking 2 seconds to find 50 matching rows from catalog, but these could easily be the first 50 rows from the catalog table..... finding 50 that match all your conditions might take longer, and not just because you need to join to other tables to get them. I would always use `create table as select` without restricting on rownum when trying to performance tune. With a complex query I would generally care about how long it take to get all the rows back... and a simple select with rownum can be misleading

Everything about Oracle performance tuning is about providing the optimizer enough information and the right tools (indexes, constraints, etc) to do its job properly. For this reason it's important to get optimizer statistics using something like `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS()`. Indexes should have stats gathered automatically in Oracle 10g or later.

Somehow this grew into quite a long answer about the Oracle optimizer. Hopefully some of it answers your question. Here is a summary of what is said above:

- Give the optimizer as much information as possible, e.g if index is unique then declare it as such.
- Add indexes on your access paths
- Find the correct times for queries without limiting by rowwnum. It will always be quicker to find the first 50 M&Ms in a jar than finding the first 50 red M&Ms
- Gather optimizer stats
- Add unique/primary keys on all tables where they exist.

Comment: That ended up being a lot longer than I intended! And probably less useful than I intended too. Oh well!

Answer (score 0):

The use of rownum is wrong and causes all the rows to be processed. It will process all the rows, assigned them all a row number, and then find those between 0 and 50. When you want to look for in the explain plan is `COUNT STOPKEY` rather than just count

The query below should be an improvement as it will only get the first 50 rows... but there is still the issue of the joins to look at too:

```
SELECT ccc.* FROM (
  SELECT cc.*, ROWNUM AS n FROM (
      SELECT c.id, c.name, c.owner
        FROM catalog c
        WHERE c.root = 100
        ORDER BY name
    ) cc 
    where rownum <= 50
) ccc WHERE ccc.n > 0 AND ccc.n <= 50;
```

Also, assuming this for a web page or something similar, maybe there is a better way to handle this than just running the query again to get the data for the next page.

Comment: I edited my question, i need to select any 50 rows ordered by name, not only first.

Comment: If you change the 50 in both places, then this query will still do less work than the original, probably even when processing the second to last page.

Answer (score -1):

try to declare a cursor. I dont know oracle, but in SqlServer would look like this:

```
declare @result 
table ( 
    id numeric,
    name varchar(255)
); 

declare __dyn_select_cursor cursor LOCAL SCROLL DYNAMIC for 

--Select
select distinct 
    c.id, c.name
From [catalog] c
    inner join university u
    on     u.catalog = c.id
       and u.university = 300
    inner join catalog_securitygroup s
    on     s.catalog = c.id
       and s.securitygroup = 200
Where
    c.root = 100
Order by name   

--Cursor
declare @id numeric;
declare @name varchar(255);

open __dyn_select_cursor; 

fetch relative 1 from __dyn_select_cursor into @id,@name declare @maxrowscount int 

set @maxrowscount = 50

while (@@fetch_status = 0 and @maxrowscount <> 0) 
begin 
     insert into @result values (@id, @name);
     set @maxrowscount = @maxrowscount - 1;
     fetch next from __dyn_select_cursor into  @id, @name; 
end 
close __dyn_select_cursor; 
deallocate __dyn_select_cursor; 


--Select temp, final result
select 
 id, 
 name
from @result;
```

Comment: I think you're posting a SQL Server answer. Never seen @@ in Oracle.

Comment: The idea is valid, though.  Oracle supports cursors.

Comment: Nah, idea is not valid until set based approach is properly attempted - and looking at the PLANs posted, it was not.

Comment: Agreed @unreason, In Oracle land, we call this approach Slow-by-Slow (row-by-row). SQL Can always beat it if the same conditions are understood. IOW, you may code a faster cursor for loop but if you do, you're applying a level of understanding of the data not available to the optimizer.